# Add border to text which is position absolute on position relative image

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm currently designing a website which has an image at the top which is position: relative with text on top which is position: absolute.

When I try to add a border to 'Contact' it has a gap at the bottom due to its position which is relative to the image. How do I make it so the border only goes around 'Contact'?

[What happens now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxPvp.jpg)
 [What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPlIU.jpg)

Code:

HTML:

```
<main>
    <div class="relative">
        <img id="headerImage" src="http://www.yugangliang.com/Library/DHTML/Gal_JJP/Photos/Joseph_Johnson_VA_Richmond_Elevated_RR_View_2100x802.jpg" alt="bridge"/>
        <p class="absolute-text" id="fontStyle">HAPPY NATIONAL PI DAY + 0.01.</p>
        <a class="absolute-text" id="fontStyle2" href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
    </div>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
    #headerImage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}

.relative{ 
    position:relative; 
    width:100%;
}

.absolute-text {
    color: white;
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:0;  
    /*padding:220px 20px;*/
    top: 150px;
    width:100%; 
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}   

#fontStyle {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 64px;
}

#fontStyle2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    /*border: 2px solid #fff !important;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    top: 290px;
    /*padding-top: 155px;*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your `#fontStyle2` CSS rule in this way:

```
#fontStyle2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    border: 2px solid #fff !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    top: 290px;
    width: auto;
    left: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```